# Continuity at a point.

Tags: limits, continuity

If the function

$$F(x,y) = \frac{x^3y^3}{x^3+y^3}$$

continuous at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

It says not continuous at that point in my book but my answer is continuous. 
Here $F(0,0) =0$.

Comment: How did you get that it's continuous?

Comment: @T.S.L By putting y=mx^n

Comment: @T.S.L using two path test such that for all m and n in R, the limit equals 0. So may be its continuous

Comment: What needs to be true for a function to be continuous? That is, what does the definition require?

Comment: @pjs36 that the limit value does not depend on m

Comment: Consider carefully the three conditions listed here. Do they all hold? -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions

Comment: Are you sure it is true for *all* $m$ and $n$?  Hint: $x^3$ is odd.

Comment: @deinst I tried it and again its coming continuous. Can you help a lil bit

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger got it now

Comment: It's not even defined in a full neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to be continuous, for every sequence $(x_n ,y_n)$ whose limit is $(0,0)$ it should be the case that $f(x_n,y_n)$ has limit 0, given that $f(0,0) = 0$ in your question.

If we find a SINGLE sequence of points $(x_n ,y_n)$ for which this is false then $f$ CANNOT be continuous.

Now I was hard pressed to find such a sequence, although I did get the following example:

Consider any sequence $x_n$ that converges to 0 and $y_n = -x_n$. Clearly $y_n$ also must converge to 0, yet we have that

$$ x_n^3 + y_n^3 = x_n^3 + (-x_n^3) = 0$$

So $f(x_n,y_n) = \frac{x_n^3 y_n^3}{x_n^3 + y_n^3} = \frac{\text{something that converges to 0 but is never equal to 0}}{0}$

And this doesn't converge to 0, as it is NEVER EVER defined for any finite index.

You could have hesitation here, for you want to consider whether one can have a notion of a sequence converging, EVEN if that sequence isn't defined for any individual terms.

Recall however the definition of convergence, that $A_n$ converges to $L$ if for every $ \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta \in \Bbb{N} \  |  \ \forall k > \delta, \  |A_k - L|< \epsilon$.

Here we can pick our $\epsilon$ but we will never, for any $\epsilon$ find a finite $\delta$ suitable for the definition of convergence and so we conclude that this, never defined sequence, couldn't even by the strangest mechanisms formally converge to 0 at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a graph of the function from WolframAlpha:

[image: Graph of {x^3 * y^3}/{x^3 + y^3}]

To corroborate what @frogeyedpeas said in his answer, consider approaching the origin along the line $y = -x$.